# Extracting values from a summary output

Tags: r

I run this code and I get following output.

```
> df$postStrata
[[1]]
[[1]]
  [1] 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2
 [48] 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2
 [95] 1 2 2 2 2 1
attr(,"oldweights")
  [1] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [10] 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [19] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [28] 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [37] 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698
 [46] 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [55] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737
 [64] 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [73] 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [82] 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [91] 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698
[100] 0.7894737
attr(,"weights")
  [1] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [10] 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [19] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [28] 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [37] 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698
 [46] 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [55] 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737
 [64] 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [73] 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698
 [82] 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 0.7894737 0.7894737
 [91] 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 0.7894737 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698 1.2790698
[100] 0.7894737
```

Is there a way I can extract the **attr(,"weights")** values. Is there a code to put the values into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the `list` element and then use `attr`

```
attr(df$postStrata[[1]][[1]], "weights")
```

---

If we need to extract from all elements of the list

```
lapply(df$postStrata, function(x) attr(x[[1]], "weights"))
```

Comment: many many thanks. I've been using R quite a bit recently, and haven't been sure how to extract the numbers from the summary's. Sometimes I've even had to resort to copy and paste! This is very helpful. Thanks